# symfony float type error message

Tags: php, symfony, annotations

I'm a little new to symfony. I have a problem with an entity and his annotations and the specific error message linked. Below, you can see the entity attributes and the specific annotations.

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="chest", type="float")
 *
 * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="The value {{ value }} is not a type {{ type }} valid.")
 *
 */
private $chest;
```

If I add this field in my forms as a text field, I get the right error message specify in the entity.(ex de msg : The value "222"" is not a type float valid)

```
$builder->add('chest', 'text')
```

But If I add this field as a number field, I get a generic error message. (ex: This value is not valid)

```
$builder->add('chest', 'number')
```

I saw, that for this kind of forms field, there is the invalid_message attributes where I can put my specific error message and it works, but I don't like to separate the way to set error message depending on the field type.

Maybe I totally wrong, Iam little bit confusing about these.

Many thanks in advance for your help

Gilles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This Type constraint checks whether your property is a **float** value.

If you use text type, (and if you have a basic setter) "chest" property will be a string. So it will always fail on this test.

If you use number type, the form tries to transform the submitted textual value into a number. When it's not possible you'll get the message that you setted at the "invalid_message" option (or the default).

I recommend you to use the number type in your form if "chest" is strict float.

Or you can set the Type constraint "type" option to "numeric". It's accept string value which is in numeric format. See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Hope it helps! :)

**UPDATE**

If I would face a problem like this, I would organize my error messages into the validator's language file.

In the Entity:

```
/**
 * @var float
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="chest", type="float")
 *
 * @Assert\Type(type="float", message="chest.invalid")
 */
private $chest;
```

In the Form Type:

```
$builder->add('chest', 'number', array(
    "invalid_message" => "chest.invalid",
    "invalid_message_parameters" => array(
        "{{ type }}" => "float"
    )
));
```

In the validation language file:

```
# app/Resources/translations/validators.en.yml

chest.invalid: The value {{ value }} is not a type {{ type }} valid.
```

(after that cache clearing is required)

Comment: Ok I understand why the test failed when I use the text type. My concerns was the difference on the way to specify error message depending on the form type used. I would like to only specify error message in the entity.

Comment: Is "chest" absolutely has to be a float? If not, add chest as text to your form, and use the Type constraint w/ "numeric" value in the "type" option. In this case you only have to define your error message there.

Comment: unfortunately it has to be float :(

Comment: The error is in the FormType. I had a TransformationFailedException: Unable to transform data for property path "southlatitude": Expected a numeric string. Once changed to $builder->add('southlatitude', NumberType::class, []) it works. The entity method is type hinted and the value looks as expected

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because **both data and form field type** have separate `Constraint`s.

Since you already have set constraints on data itself, I would think it's safe to remove those of form type.

You could probably do something like this (although, I have never tried it):

```
$builder->add('chest', 'number', array('constraints': null))
```

Does this work?

Comment: No It change nothing, I still get the generic error message, not the one specify in the entity with annotations.

Comment: I have gone over the source of `NumberType` class and could not find the evidence of that message. Hmm, I'll look some more and let you know if I think of anything else ;)